# Spring Cloud Config : Password not getting decrypted with jasypt in spring cloud config client when actuator/refresh endpoint is called

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, jasypt, spring-cloud-config-server

I am setting up spring cloud config server (2.2.0.RELEASE) and config client using git as repository.
Also I am encrypting value inside properties file using jasypt-spring-boot-starter (2.1.2).

**Example  - inside app.properties**

```
   password: ENC(cppertuvnh)
```

When the config loads for the first time from config server, the encrypted values (i.e. password) are getting properly decrypted at config client but later when i call a actuator/refresh endpoint, the encrypted value is passed as it is and not getting decrypted in config client.

**Is there a way by which jasypt will again decrypt properties in spring config client after refresh endpoint is called?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new version 3.0.3 is fix this problem：

```
Update 05/31/2020: Version 3.0.3 Release Includes
Minor bug fixes
Documentation fixes
Refresh event fix for spring cloud config
```

https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot#update-05312020-version-303-release-includes